# WCF Service hosted in Windows Service stops responding

Tags: wcf, windows-services, nettcpbinding

Our WCF service is hosted in a Windows Service using net tcp binding with port 8090.

It works well for the most part, but from time to time, client applications fail to connect to the service, even if the service is still running and there are no apparent errors in the event log.  The client application will get the following exception while connecting:

> The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00.  The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

The client machine is still able to ping the server.

Restarting the windows service solves the problem, but users don't like it.

Any idea what could be happening here?  I've read about the Net TCP Listener service and making sure the server has been patched.  But I think that's only for net tcp binding hosted in IIS, and might not be applicable in my case.

Thanks!

Here's the service configuration:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="behavior1" name="Tamer.Service.WcfService">
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpLarge" name="endpoint1" contract="Tamer.Service.Library.IFundService" />
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpLarge" name="endpoint2" contract="Tamer.Service.Library.IEntitlementService" />
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpLarge" name="endpoint3" contract="Tamer.Service.Library.IReferenceDataService" />
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpLarge" name="endpoint4" contract="Tamer.Service.Library.ITransactionService" />
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpLarge" name="endpoint4" contract="Tamer.Service.Library.IDocumentService" />
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpLarge" name="endpoint5" contract="Tamer.Service.Library.IFileStreaming" />
    <endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTcpLarge" name="endpoint6" contract="Tamer.Service.Library.IReportService" />
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8091/mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" name="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="behavior1">
      <serviceMetadata policyVersion="Policy15" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="192"  maxConcurrentSessions="192" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpLarge" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
      receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="01:00:00" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxConnections="192" listenBacklog="100">
      <!--listenBacklog="100"-->
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
                          maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                          maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <message clientCredentialType="None"/>
        <transport protectionLevel="None" clientCredentialType="None"/>
      </security>
      <!--reliableSession enabled="false"/-->

    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Can you show configuration parameters of your service and client applications? Your problem can be result of number of old open connections between client and server applications.

Comment: @AlexanderKiselev Just added the service config.  Thanks.